# Different output if at end of function rather that in main after function concludes

Tags: c++

The function reverses the given string. How come the output is only half the string when I output it at the end of the function, but the whole string reversed if I output it at the end of the function call?

```
void reverse(char* str);

int main() {
    char test[] = "My input!";
    reverse(test);
    std::cout << test;
```

**Output here is: !tupni yM**

```
    return 0;
}

void reverse(char *str) { 
     char* end = str; 
     char tmp; 
    if (str) { 
        while (*end) { /* find end of the string */ 
            ++end; 
            } 
        --end; /* set one char back, since last char is null */ 

        while (str < end) { 
            tmp = *str; 
            *str++ = *end; 
            *end-- = tmp; 
        } 
     }
     std::cout << str << endl;
```

**Output here is: ni yM**

```
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The value of the pointer `str` is changed in the function, store its original value in the beginning of the function:

```
char *original_str = str;
```

and print it at the end:

```
std::cout << original_str << std::endl;
```

You can see it's the same as in the `main`.

Answer (score 0):

I realized that I moved the str pointer about half way down the string within the reverse() method. So when I printed it out it would only start from about half way down the string. But the original c-string was modified and its pointer is still pointing to the beginning of the string.